# How to stop animation in jQuery, but when animation is finished first

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-animate

I need help with auto slider animation.So, my question is - how to stop animation on hover event, but not immediately, rather when animation on the separate element is completely finished.

I have this piece of code:

```
$(function(){

   var current_slide=1;
   var set_time=2500;

   $('span').css({top:'300px'});

   $.timer(6000,function(timer){
      switch(current_slide){
         case 1:
            $('span').css({top:'350px'});
            $('#slideshow').stop().animate({left:'-960px',top:'0px'},{easing:'easeOutBack',duration:set_time});
            current_slide=2;
            $('span').delay(2500).animate({top:'300px'});
            break;
         case 2:
            $('span').css({top:'350px'});
            $('#slideshow').stop().animate({left:'-1920px',top:'0px'},{easing:'easeOutBack',duration:set_time});
            current_slide=3;
            $('span').delay(2500).animate({top:'300px'});
            break;
         case 3:
            $('span').css({top:'350px'});
            $('#slideshow').stop().animate({left:'-2880px',top:'0px'},{easing:'easeOutBack',duration:set_time});
            current_slide=4;
             $('span').delay(2500).animate({top:'300px'});
            break;

         case 4:
            $('span').css({top:'350px'});
            $('#slideshow').stop().animate({left:'0px',top:'0px'},{easing:'easeOutExpo',duration:set_time});
            current_slide=1;
            $('span').delay(2500).animate({top:'300px'});
            break;
      }

      timer.reset(12000);
   });

   $("#slideshow").hover(function(){
      $(this).stop(true,true);
   });
});
```

The trouble is when I hover over the slider, then the animation stopped(jumping to the end) hardly,abruptly and ugly.May be I should use queue before .stop(), or something like this.
Here is good example: http://www.sevtopolishotel.com/
Tnx in advance!

Comment: Take 15 seconds and properly format that code, a little bit of indenting + line spaces goes a long way with regards to readability.

Comment: Your `case 3` has a break that is not immediately before the next case. This is unintentional, right? If so, this code can be refactored a great deal.

Comment: May I also suggest the author of the question takes a look at caching jQuery selectors, that'll tidy things up and improve performance.

Comment: [suggested refactoring](http://jsfiddle.net/zTykj/)

Comment: Now code is formate, and ready for smooth reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could track hover state like this:

```
var isHovered = false;
$("#slideshow").hover(function(e){
    isHovered = e.type == 'mouseenter';
});
```

From there, it would be possible to wrap your entire switch in `if(!isHovered) { ... }`, which would mean that as long as the slideshow is hovered, the timer would skip immediately to just setting the next timeout.

Comment: This solve my PROBLEM. tnx,tnx,tnx alote mate, respect.... Now code work perfect.

Comment: Congratulations for simple but effectivе,and fast answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the .stop() documentation : http://api.jquery.com/stop/

It is written there that you can pass an argument for "jumpToEnd". If that argument is false, then the animation continues until end. I think your code should look something like this:

```
$("#slideshow").hover(function(){
          $(this).stop(true,false);
    });  });
```

Comment: Without jumping to end, `stop` will just leave the animation hanging at its current state, won't it? This is quite different from allowing the animation to finish and then stopping.

Comment: tnx for advice, but when i change .stop(true,true) to .stop(true,false), then it becomes worse, the image is stopped immediately on the half way.

Comment: Yes, it seems I was wrong. You could set a variable wasStop = false, and make it true at hover. Add a callback function at the end of your animation and check if stopped==true, then apply .stop on your element.

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5yhYD/4/ . If you click on the second square before the first gets to margin-left:200px, then the first div will stop at 200px, else it will come back.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold a reference to the timer . then rather than stoping the animation you just clear the timer which is schenduling the animation. so the current animation will be going but none will be scheduled to run again.
if you are using javascript setTimeout you can do this

```
vat timer=setTimeout(animation_function, delay);
 //to stop later
clearTimeOut(timer);
```

but I think you  are using a jquery timer plugin  Still your $.timer plugin should have a clear method to stop running again check the document .

look at this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955311/my-javascript-function-runs-in-duplicate-when-i-add-click-event/9956228#9956228) is almost the same issue.